# Microsoft VS 2022 with .NET 6.0 Error: The debug executable...debug profile does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

I started to learn C# and .NET and just installed Microsoft VS 2022 and also installed .NET 6.0. I was trying to run the first code and the error came up as follows. I did some research but couldn't figure out what's wrong. I noticed there is a similar question on StackOverflow before. I tried the answers but didn't work.

Can anyone help please?

The error message:

```
The debug executable 'C:\user\owener\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\net6.0\ConsoleApp2.exe'specified in the 'ConsoleApp2' debug profile does not exist.
```

Output showing error message:

```
error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'C:\user\owener\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\obj\project.assets.json'not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Tools->NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console and type

```
dotnet restore
```

or you can first go in settings and search for Nuget->General and Clear the Caches

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but was stuck at initializing power shell host.

Answer (score 0):

It is all fixed now. debug, Nuget, PowerShell are all working. I just uninstalled VS 2022 and reinstalled VS 2019 and ticked all extra optional when choosing .Net desktop development. I guess I'm missing some software in my computer system.

Comment: Please accept your own answer. If issue fixed.